# TypeScript use dynamic import in ES5 with Bluebird

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to use the new dynamic `import()` function in TypeScript, but I get the following error:

> **TS2712:** A dynamic import call in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise'
>   constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise'
>   constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.

I could include the `ES2015.promise` lib in my tsconfig like the message suggests, but that would make me lose type safety as I'm using Bluebird promises.

I know it is possible to use Bluebird for `async/await` in TypeScript, so I suppose this should also work the same way.

---

**The message also mentions this:**

> Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or [...]

Is it possible to declare the Bluebird constructor to be used as the Promise constructor in TS?

---

*Example code:*

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

// This works
async function exampleAsync(): Bluebird<number> {
    const result = await Bluebird.resolve(5);
    return result;
}

// This does not
import('jquery').then($ => {
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
});
```

*TSConfig:*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es2015.collection"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171651/typescript-promise-constructor-declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript is looking for a *global* `Promise`. What you have in your code is a `Promise` declared in a module ("bluebird") and used locally in another module.

Here's a minimal way to get the compilation errors to be resolve and to have runnable code:

`test.ts`:

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';

declare global {
    const Promise: {
        new <R>(callback: (
            resolve: (thenableOrResult?: R | PromiseLike<R>) => void,
            reject: (error?: any) => void,
            onCancel?: (callback: () => void) => void
        ) => void): Bluebird<R>;
    };
}

import('jquery').then($ => {
    console.log($);
});
```

I've modified the `console.log` statement to just output `$` so that the code above can be readily run in Node rather than require a browser. (When you load `jquery` in Node, you get a constructor that needs a `Window` instance from which you then build the same kind of `jQuery` object you immediately get when you load `jquery` in a window. So `$.fn.jquery` is not accessible.)

I'm using the following `tsconfig.json` which I derived from yours:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": ["es5", "dom", "es2015.collection"]
  }
}
```

You had a couple unnecessary options in there, and `skipLibCheck` is necessary to handle issues `@types/jquery`.

Comment: The `jquery` module was just an example and I'm actually running it in the browser so that would be no problem. But thanks a lot for the working solution!