# TypeScript promise constructor declaration

Tags: typescript, promise, bluebird

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149091/typescript-use-dynamic-import-in-es5-with-bluebird/45170452#45170452) when I noticed a weird behavior in TypeScript declaration of Promise constructor:

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird'

interface PromiseConstructor {
    new <R>(callback: (resolve: (thenableOrResult?: R | PromiseLike<R>) => void, reject: (error?: any) => void, onCancel?: (callback: () => void) => void) => void): Bluebird<R>;
}

declare var Promise: PromiseConstructor;

// This works:
const x: PromiseLike<any> = new Promise<any>((a,b) => void 0);

// This does not work:
import('jquery').then($ => {
    console.log($.fn.jquery)
});

// This doesn't work either:
async function test() {
  return "";
}
```

As you can see, I declare the constructor and it lets me to build a promise, and it doesn't blame about not being of type PromiseLike. But I can't use async functions or deferred import. The compiler `Version 2.5.0-dev.20170629` blames with this message twice:

> test.ts(13,1): error TS2712: A dynamic import call in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your --lib option.

How must I declare the PromiseConstructor so?

Comment: Your problem is the same as in the question you were trying to answer.  The declaration must be global, but you have a local declaration.