# Getting error TS2712 even when including es2015 and/or es2015.promise in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-5

I have a project that is targeting ES5, and is using dynamic imports.

I have tried including both es2015 and es2015.promise in my tsconfig.json, and in both cases I still get the TS2712: a dynamic import call in ES5/ES3 ... error message.

Is there something that I am missing in terms of how to make Typescript allow dynamic imports when targeting ES5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript use dynamic import in ES5 with Bluebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149091/typescript-use-dynamic-import-in-es5-with-bluebird)

Comment: I had the same problem in an angular project. What helped now is that I updated the @types/node in the dev dependencies from 9.6.1 to 10.14.22 and now the problem does not show up anymore in vscode.